# select statement where condition not equal to other in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table in mysql database. table 'sell_stats'

```
+-------------------+-----------+--------+
|  id   | max_price | sell_price| orders |
+-------------------+-----------+--------+
|  1    |   120     | 110       |  1     |
|  2    |   324     | 324       |  0     |
|  3    |   445     | 445       |  1     |
|  4    |   654     | 654       |  1     |
|  5    |   657     | 657       |  0     |
|  6    |   456     | 456       |  2     |
+-----------------+-------------+--------+
```

I want to find those columns in which **max_price != sell_price**

i wrote this query for that

```
select * from  sell_stats where max_price != sell_price;
```

but i am getting the error

```
ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function.
```

then i tried grouping them on id, but still the same error.

```
select * from  sell_stats where max_price != sell_price group by id;
```

please   can anyone help me in this?

Comment: I don't see how you can get that error from the query you wrote. Group functions are things like `MAX()`, `COUNT()`, and `GROUP_CONCAT()`, and you have none of those in your query.

Comment: Your query works fine: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a302/1

Comment: Agree with @Barmar. I guess the error raised from the other query, not this one.

Comment: I looked at several other SO questions about "Invalid use of group function". They all had functions like that in the `WHERE` clause, such as `WHERE sell_price != MAX(price)`.

Comment: I am trying to your query but i can't find any issue.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
select * from  sell_stats where max_price <> sell_price;
```

Comment: Why would that be any different? `!=` and `<>` are interchangeable.

Comment: Indeed, I normally use `<>` and I know that this statement is correct.

Comment: But why would using `!=` cause an error about group functions?

Comment: My guess is that the he is (unaware) running several statements at the same time (imagine you have Workbench and a query sheet with several selects), and the error is triggered by the last. Another possibility is that we are not seeing the complete query (like tokas suggests).

Comment: Indeed. That's why I wouldn't waste time posting an answer until we get the real picture. Suggesting that he change `!=` to `<>` is an obvious waste of time.

Comment: See? Many times (at least in my case) getting obvious suggestions/answers to questions caused me to re-think and solve the problem by myself. I see this forum as a channel through which we ALL get help in any possible way. In this case, it took me 10 secs to post my answer, and I'm willing to spend this time if it is of help. That is my way of honoring the people that created this fantastic site. Of course, this is only my personal opinion and nobody is forced to agree with me.

Comment: IMHO, posting an answer that can't possibly be right is bad. The OP will waste time trying to use it to see if it helps, instead of clarifying the question. Use the comments section to try to get him to clarify the question, then we can get back to the work of solving real problems.

Comment: OK, I respect your position but select to exercise my freedom to disagree. Thank you anyway for your thoughts.

Comment: And I hope you respect my freedom to downvote. I didn't single you out, I also downvoted the answer that suggested `NOT max_price = sell_price`, since it's just as worthless.

Comment: No problem, don't worry. I do it for the fun, not for the points.